# Login site using cURL

Tags: curl

I am trying to login from cURL command line with the command

curl --data "username=user&password=pass&submit=Login" http://www.ip.com:8080/LoginApplication/Login.jsp

And after that trying to access inner page using

```
curl http://www.ip.com:8080/LoginApplication/Success.jsp
```

But I am getting redirected to error page because of not logged in.

What I am missing in my first command so that it can maintain the session?
I have my website locally hosted

Comment: possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, you'll need to store the session data in a cookie. You can use `-c cookie_filename` to create the cookie (add this to your login command). And then, for the other requests, you can read from the cookie with `-b cookie_filename`.

In example:

```
curl -s loginpage -c cookiefile -d "user=myself&pass=secure"
curl -s secretpage -b cookiefile
```

**EDIT**:

Notice many times `loginpage` is not the page you open with your web browser where you introduce your user and password. You'll have to check where the form is posting that data to (search the `<form>` tag in the source code and the `action=...` attribute). So, for example, if you want to log in to https://criticker.com, `loginpage` is https://www.criticker.com/authenticate.php and not https://www.criticker.com/signin.php, which is the one you open with your browser.

A tampering plugin/extension for your browser may help you find the correct `loginpage` and all the data that is being posted to it (like hidden input fields in the form).

Comment: Given sequence of -s -c -d doesnot even producing cookie file

Comment: It was a great help, I looked my source again and found my request is going to a controller and then I modified my command and it worked for me.

Comment: This works fine for HTTP, is there anything I need to do extra with HTTPS

Comment: @SAR: you are having problems with certificates. Maybe you just want to use `-k`. See `curl --help` for more information or search on the internet how to handle certificates. ;-)

Comment: Thank you the great help...Issue with my curl was, "Notice many times loginpage is not the page you open with your web browser where you introduce your user and password. "...Thank you!

Comment: @Peque I'm trying to login to page that you've mentioned but I'm unable to, please check my question, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391862/login-to-page-using-html-form-and-cookies-for-authentication